# Render huge list in select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a PHP application where a list of people is displayed in a select box. With time this list is now more than 100,000 long and the screen takes about 20-25 seconds to load. Is there any way I can cut down on this time? Tried loading the names via ajax, but the performance is same or worse. This also needs to be the first item selected on screen, as the rest of the items are dependent on it.

Comment: instead of giving it in select, make it in a autocomplete textbox using ajax

Comment: Can you break the list into subgroups?

Comment: In cases where dropdowns grow large, most people usually go over to a autocomplete solution. Maybe take a look at jquery-ui autocomplete?

Comment: if items in list doesn't change often,you could output the list to an html file and recreate it from time to time. Then include it in php script

Comment: It is a list of registered patients in a hospital. So, I can't break it into subgroups. Its based on a old custom developed PHP framework, and generates SELECT by default. I have limited freedom and was hoping for a way to render the items more quickly. Will try implementing autocomplete though. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax as you already tried, but instead of displaying all names, you could do something like autocomplete, which will display matching names when users start typing.

Example in jQuery: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Will try autocomplete, and see how it turns out

Answer (score 0):

Can u use [jScroll](http://jscroll.com/)?
you can just implement in your select dropdown, by replacing the contents to your list items.

Or you can see this.. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SPZn4/2/)

```
ember.js
```